# I lost my Azure SQL database, but I have .bacpac file. Can I somehow open it?

Tags: sql, database, azure, bacpac

So I was using Microsoft Azure trial version and I made SQL server and database. I made a backup and got .bacpac file exported. I've just logged in and saw that I lost my database because my free trial expired. Can I somehow still open database using .bacpac file? I sent an email to their support, but still waiting for the response.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question at dba.stackexchange.com. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: Check this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to restore my data!

Answer (score 0):

Of course. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import):

```
$importRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport 
   -ResourceGroupName "<your_resource_group>" `
   -ServerName "<your_server>" `
   -DatabaseName "<your_database>" `
   -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "<database_size_in_bytes>" `
   -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
   -StorageKey $(Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "<your_resource_group>" -StorageAccountName "<your_storage_account").Value[0] `
   -StorageUri "https://myStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/importsample/sample.bacpac" `
   -Edition "Standard" `
   -ServiceObjectiveName "P6" `
   -AdministratorLogin "<your_server_admin_account_user_id>" `
   -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<your_server_admin_account_password>" -AsPlainText -Force)
```